# Jquery animated circular nav

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, jquery-animate, carousel

I have a friend who is looking for the following sort of navigation. They have explained it as the logo in the middle and then the other logos ‘orbiting’ around it. As the other logos move around you can select ‘it’ and it will take you to the pages.

Can anyone recommend the best way to achieve this? where to start with this. Any demo’s anyone can show me?
The closest thing I can think to accomplish this might be some sort of Jquery 3d carousel, however this isn’t what they are looking to achieve.

I have linked to an image as an example of what they are looking for: 
http://tinypic.com/r/ibaptv/7

Answer (score 0):

You could try animating their top and left element using the sine and cosine functions to create the circular motion.

I'll test some and get back to you

Comment: Any thoughts on this? I have been looking into this further but so far with no luck